# not receiving relations from database

Tags: typeorm

I have a user table, and one of the columns is contacts which references itself. Now I am trying to get all the user’s contacts. However it is not returning the references. I am not exactly sure are to where the problem can be. Lets say I have a user table that looks like this

```
id | name    |        email              | contacts_Id
---|---------|---------------------------|-----
1  | foo     | foo@foo.com               | 2
2  | bar     | bar@bar.com               | 1
3  | baz     | baz@baz.com               | 1 2
```

The entity is like this:

```js
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public email: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.contacts, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  public contact: User;

  @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.contact)
  public contacts: User[];
}
```

and I am querying like this:

```js
const userRepo = getManager().getRepository('users');
const data = (await userRepo.findOne({ where: { email: email }, relations: ['contacts'] })) as UserData;
```

with the code above I get the user data (id, name, email) the contacts section is empty `[]`

### solved:

change:

```js
const data = (await userRepo.findOne({ where: { email: email }, relations: ['contacts'] })) as UserData;
```

*to*

```js
const data = (await userRepo.findOne({ where: { email: email }, relations: ['contacts'] })) as User;
```

since we are referencing the entity

Answer (score 0):

I literally did the same thing (copied your entity), difference being that I injected repository into my service, I'm using mySQL, and I guess you're using PostgreSQL but it works for me. 
The thing that is bugging me is your column contacts_Id, by default typeorm will generate a camel case foreign key column (contactId) unless specified differently by JoinColumn() decorator, so maybe that's what causing the issues.
(I wanted to comment but don't have enough rep to post a comment.)